# Javafx outofmemory error

Tags: javafx

i am trying to run simple JavaFx(2.0) application which will show three images as thumbnails. OS is Windows7 and i am using NetBeans 7.2
Code is this-

```
public class FX17 extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage stage){

        HBox photoBar = new HBox();
        Group root = new Group();
        File f1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\IMG_0021.jpg");
        File f2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\IMG_0022.jpg");
        File f3 = new File("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\IMG_0023.jpg");

        Image i1 = new Image(f1.toURI().toString());
        Image i2 = new Image(f2.toURI().toString());
        Image i3 = new Image(f3.toURI().toString());
        ImageView iv1 = new ImageView(i1);
        //iv1.setImage(i1);
        iv1.setFitWidth(50);
        iv1.setPreserveRatio(true);
        iv1.setCache(true);

        ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(i2);
        //iv2.setImage(i2);
        iv2.setFitWidth(50);
        iv2.setPreserveRatio(true);
        iv2.setCache(true);

        ImageView iv3 = new ImageView(i3);
       // iv3.setImage(i3);
        iv3.setFitWidth(50);
        iv3.setPreserveRatio(true);
        iv3.setCache(true);

       photoBar.getChildren().add(iv1);
        photoBar.getChildren().add(iv2);
        photoBar.getChildren().add(iv3);
        //C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(photoBar);
        root.getChildren().add(photoBar);
        //pane.setLeft(linkBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(415);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

For two images program runs and shows two thumbnails but for 3 or more images, program throws OutOfMemoryError. Image is jpg and average size is 2.5MB. Are there some setting or image format i need to check ?
Following constructor works fine for me.
Image img = new Image(file.toURI().toString(),100,100,false,false);aspect ratio,smooth is false.

Comment: Hi all,following constructor works fine-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your jpgs are very large in terms of height and width.

The memory taken by a jpg versus the loaded image buffer is different. The loaded image is a decoded uncompressed bitmap and depends on the image height/width/color depth rather than the original jpg file size.

To fix your OutOfMemory condition:

1. Resize the jpgs to a smaller height and width (and/or lower color depth) using an image editor outside your program AND/OR
2. Only load a single jpg into memory at a time, rather than all three at once AND/OR
3. Increase the memory available to your java app (e.g. -Xmx1500m) AND/OR
4. Specify a size in the image constructor rather than the image view.

Specifying a size in the image constructor ensures that, once the image is loaded, Java only keeps a buffer large enough to hold the resized image rather than the full size, uncompressed image.